# Create a subset of a dataset with a specific grid size in ArcGIS using Data Management Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip, data-management

I am wondering how you can create a subset of a dataset that is a specific grid size (in pixels) using the Clip tool within the Data Management Tool box for raster data.

I was trying to find a hint where to set the grid size in the tool's Environment Settings, but the result, after running the tool, did not apply the new grid size.

Please does anyone handled this before?

Comment: You can specify the raster size by column and row via right-clicking the Raster layer in the TOC > Data > Export Raster Data.

Answer (score 1):

In the ArcGIS Help is described, which environment settings apply to the respective tools. The cell size environment setting is only supported by a few tools. In the ArcGIS Help you find the following:
Tools that honor the Cell size environment setting set the output raster cell size, or resolution, for the operation.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000001s000000

If want to find out which environment settings are supported by a tool, you have to check the ArcGIS Help. Cell size is not listed on the Clip (Data Management) ArcGIS Help site: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000009n000000 (section Environments)

If you still want to use the Clip function you need to apply the Resample (Data Management) tool to get the required cell size and afterwards the Clip tool.

An alternative is the Spatial Analyst Tool Extract by Mask: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extract_by_Mask/009z0000002n000000/
Cell size is listed under environments on the ArcMap Help site. Thus, it should output the specific grid size (pixel size).

Comment: How is resampling relevant to this OP's question?  Thanks for the clarification.